# How to get confirm password when I use Ethereum Wallet by ganache development?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm writing smart contracts in Ethereum, using `ganache` and `truffle`. Contracts was deployed to the chains and I use Ethereum Wallet to get all the accounts created by `ganache`, but when I want to test the contracts or send eth I get this information:

[image]

And I got the private key but Ethereum Wallet import account is disabled:

[image]

How do I use these accounts to test my contracts by Ethereum Wallet?